# To upload image in wordpress from External link

Tags: php, wordpress

I have image coming from external link

```
http://deomain.com/images.php?id=<id>
```

Now I want to upload image using above url into wordpress.

Please suggest code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get started go ahead and download [Grab and Save](http://wordpress.org/plugins/save-grab/) plugin. Once you have it downloaded and activated you will notice that whenever you went to add an image to a post “Grab & Save” will be one of the options you have available to you.

[image]

If you click on it you are taken to a screen where you just enter the URL of the image you would like to upload and Grab & Save will do the rest. So, now you can upload images directly simply by using their URL.

Comment: This plugin is only working with the url have extension .png,.jpg etc. but please check my url is different.

Comment: Bhumi, Can you post your real url here?